# Trying to open chrome on my profile with selenium in python 3.8

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chrome-web-driver

Every time chrome opens it's not on my profile, so I don't have all of my saved passwords an extensions.
I searched for a while and this is what came out.
Chrome still opens but it's not on my profile.
Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1")

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.nike.com/it/launch?s=upcoming")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a comma after path and then define chrome_options like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
```